# Save File Using Common Dialog in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I am trying to make a simple notepad using Python 3.4.1 using tkinter. I can open files using Windows Explorer window and get the path ([storing file path using windows explorer browser in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643418/storing-file-path-using-windows-explorer-browser-in-python) , [Choosing a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994461/choosing-a-file-in-python3)), but I couldn't find a way to save a file. If the user tries to saves a new file that didn't exist, it gives an error message that the file doesn't exist.
I used:

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
save_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=app, title='Save')
```

If I type a non-existing file name and press 'Open', it gives an error message.

Comment: `askopenfilename` is designed for choosing files to *open* (as should be obvious from the name). Why not use `asksaveasfilename`?

Answer (score 0):

Use could use the class [FileChooserDialog](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkfilechooserdialog.html) from the module `gtk`:

```
import gtk

gtk.FileChooserDialog().run()
```